# str_ireplace() not accutally removing the 'needles'

Tags: php, string, security

I'm using str_ireplace() to remove instances of strings in an array, and I'm returning the number of counted occurances, but it's not actually performing the replace.

```
//replace occurances of insert, update, delete, select
$dmlArray = array('select', 'update', 'delete', 'insert');

str_ireplace($dmlArray,'-- replaced DML -- ',$clean['comment'],$Incount);
```

Where $clean['comment'] would be the $_POST array.

For example, `$clean['comment'] = "SELECT, insert, UPDATE, DEleTe";`

The final string should be "-- replaced DML -- ,-- replaced DML -- ,-- replaced DML -- ,-- replaced DML -- ";

Yet it's not.

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: I'm getting the original string. It's like it's working, but it's not.

Comment: “It looks like you're writing a half-hearted attempt to sanitize content for insertion in an SQL string literal. Would you like help?” (\*) Get help with how to use SQL escaping instead (\*) Just carry on banging your head against it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `str_ireplace` doesn't change its arguments. It returns the result. Here is fix for your code:

```
$clean['comment'] = str_ireplace($dmlArray, '-- replaced -- ', $clean['comment'], $Incount);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run your code and it works as expected.

```
echo str_ireplace(
    array('select', 'update', 'delete', 'insert'),
    '-- replaced DML -- ',
    'SELECT, insert, UPDATE, DEleTe',
    $Incount);
```

The above will output

```
-- replaced DML -- , -- replaced DML -- , -- replaced DML -- , -- replaced DML --
```

Just keep in mind that the input string is not passed in by reference, so you have to use the return value to get the string with the values replaced.